# Click en elementos con selectores similares (python selenium)

Tags: python, selenium

Cómo puedo hacer para darle click a todos estos elementos? 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Todos tienen selectores similares, lo único que cambia entre uno y otro es el código genérico del reporte, es decir, todos los botones de esa columna Pdf tienen este id:
"filtroReportesAsincronos:tableLisReportes:5984197:linkConsultarPDF"

similarmente este xpath:
'//*[@id="filtroReportesAsincronos:tableLisReportes:5984197:linkConsultarPDF"]'

El valor variable en ese caso es el "5984197".

Cómo puedo hacer para seleccionar todos los elementos de esa columna independiente del código genérico del reporte? No es posible de pronto utilizar comodines dentro del id? y si es así como se utilizarían estos comodines?

Comment: En principio puedes probar con algo como `driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[starts-with(@id, 'filtroReportesAsincronos:tableLisReportes:') and contains(@id, ':linkConsultarPDF')]")`

Comment: Hola @FJSevilla
Intenté hacerlo como dices, de esta manera :
reportes = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[starts-with(@id, 'filtroReportesAsincronos:tableLisReportes:') and contains(@id, ':linkConsultarPDF')]")

for btn in reportes:
    btn.click()

Pero solamente le da click al primer elemento que encuentra, solo descarga uno de los pdf

Comment: ¿Qué te muestra `print(len(reportes))`? es decir ¿te encuentra todos los botones? Lo primero a descartar es ésto, si es así, es posible que no puedas descargarte todos al mismo tiempo simplemente.

Comment: ese print que dice muestra "6".

Comment: Igual apenas descarga el primer elemento el código falla, mira el log de errores.
Message: element click intercepted

Comment: ¿Es posible que se  abra algún popup o alert cuando se hace click? Eso suele indicar que otro elemento se ha interpuesto y el click que debería ir al botón termina en él. Supongo que la página no es de dominio público para poder compartirla ¿no? El scraping a veces es complicado con acceso al recurso, sin el es como disparar a moscas con un tirachinas con los ojos vendados XD

Comment: Pues cuando de la click en descargar al primer elemento, aparece en la parte de abajo de la ventana de chrome la descarga de este archivo. Si es posible que esto esté interfiriendo con el siguiente click. sabes cómo podría solucionar esto?

Answer (score 0):

De hecho puedes hacer clic uno por uno mediante un clic:

```
for e in driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('span'):
    e.click()
```